# Is there an alternative to Android app actions that support more languages

Tags: android, google-assistant, app-actions, google-voice-actions

I'm looking to add support for google assistant to my mobile map.
I tried out app actions and it works but as I can see it only supports a limited number of languages (for the intents that I need only english). From what I saw it's been the same languages for the last 2 years at least.

I also checked out the action console but conversational actions will be removed in less than a year but that had support for multiple languages.

Is there any alternative or ETA for more languages?